# Error with reading and writing long data type incrementally in C

Tags: c, integer, fopen, read-write

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  long num = 0;
  FILE *fptr;

     if ((fptr = fopen("test_num.txt","r+")) == NULL){
         printf("Error! opening file");
         return -1;
     }

     fscanf(fptr,"%ld", &num);

     // Increment counter by 1
     num += 1;

     printf("%ld\n", num);
     fprintf(fptr, "%ld", num);
     fclose(fptr);

     return -1;

}
```

With the aforementioned code I am trying to read the content of the file, which always has a long value stored and nothing else, increment the value by 1 and then overwrite the lond value of the file with the new incremented value. However, I am trying to do this without closing and file in between reading/writing. Fo example, the workflow/algorithm should be as follows:

```
Step 1: Open the file
Step 2: Read the long value from the file
Step 3: Increment the long value by 1
Step 4: Overwrite the long value of the file by new incremented value
Step 5: Close the file
```

However, if I use the aforementioned code then the output value appends the incremented value at the end of the file instead of overwriting. I have tried opening the file with "w+" and "w" but of course these only work for writing but not reading the file as mentioned above. Can anyone know what I can do to achieve the goal?

Comment: First of all, think of a text file like an array of characters, and the position in the file (the "file pointer") as the current index into that array. When you read from the file, the functions will update this index. After your call to `fscanf` the index will be *after* the data you have read, so when you write to the file it will write to that position instead and not overwrite what you just read.

Comment: You need to move the file pointer back to the beginning. [`rewind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) or [`fseek()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)

Comment: Secondly, you can't easily overwrite data in a text file. For example, if you read the value `9`, increase it to `10` and then attempt to overwrite the value, that changes the length of the data you write, and you will overwrite more than the value you did read. There are ways to work around this, but it's not trivial.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks a ton. I have inserted rewind(fptr) in the code and now it works properly.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks a ton as well. I have inserted rewind(fptr) in the code and now it works properly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude should I be worried about overwriting the length of the variable as you have mentioned? The aformentioned problem could be trivial since the code snippet above is going into real time based software. Is there any way I could imrpove the efficiency so that unexpected behaviour could be avoided?

Comment: As long as the file only contains just the one number and the number always increases, you should be fine. However, if the file contains "1234" and you try to write "56", you will end up with "5634".

Comment: Or if your file contains "12 34"  and you write "567" you would end up with "56734". Son definitely something you need to think about if you want more than a single number in the file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so what can I do to cater for that kind of an issue? Will it be possible to provide some queue from the code provided in the answer for possible improvement?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  so what can I do to cater for that kind of an issue? Will it be possible to provide some queue from the code provided in the answer for possible improvement?

Comment: The simplest solution is to open for reading, read, close, increment, open for writing, write. See: [`freopen("test_num.txt", "w")`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer happens to be: I needed to **rewind** the file ponter back to the index 0 of the file in order to overwrite the content of the file with the incremented value. The correct code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  long num = 0;
  FILE *fptr;

     if ((fptr = fopen("test_num.txt","r+")) == NULL){
         printf("Error! opening file");
         return -1;
     }

     fscanf(fptr,"%ld", &num);

     // Increment counter by 1
     num += 1;

     printf("%ld\n", num);
     rewind(fptr); // Rewind to index 0 of the fptr
     fprintf(fptr, "%ld", num);
     fclose(fptr);

     return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to rewrite parts of a text-file:

1. Read the while file into memory, make the change, and write it back out from the beginning.
2. Read parts of the file (for example line by line), making the change on the fly, and writing to a new temporary file. Then rename the temporary file as the actual file.